# WebBrowser control's rendered page differs from IE

Tags: c#

This is how it looks like on IE
[image]

And this is how it looks like on a `System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser` control
[image]

I am pretty sure that `WebBrowser` control is directly embedding IE, but why do they look different? It looks to me that only part of my style sheet got applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because default version of WebBrowser control in c# WinForms application is 7.

You need to change layout to fit IE 7 or  try to set the latest version changing registry key:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION]
"your_application_name.exe"=dword:00002328
```

Also, you can modify it from your code. [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/793687/Configuring-the-emulation-mode-of-an-Internet-Expl) is an example.

Comment: any idea what will happen if I set it to IE 9 and the user only has IE 8?

Comment: @Steve I didn't check it. We use IE 7 :(

Comment: oh well....thx anyways. The fact that it is using IE 7 instead of latest is purely dumb, you can't change it using a property is more dumb, the best part is that you are required to read/write the registry to accomplish this...

Comment: after research, it turns out that you can also add <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"> to the html meta to make it work. I am so glad I have full control on the server side as well..